The cross spectrum calculation: spec.pgram function in R
I have to do the calculation of a crosss-spectrum between two signals. I read the post "Spectral Analysis in R - the periodogram" and I understand why the periododram is symmetric. In the case of the cross-covariance cij(t), the function is not necessary symmetric so I thought that the sign of the frequency would have had an importance in the calculation. But when I try to understand the code of the spec.pgram function in R it seems not to have any difference between the calculation of a periodogram and a cross-periodogram. Could somebody explain to me why ? Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My objective is to do the calculation of the one-sided power spectral density. With only one signal, I do the calculation of the spectral density Sx(f) with f in the range of [-fs/2 , fs/2] and then I deduce the one-sided Power Spectral Density with Px(f) = 2 * Sx(f) with f only over [0, fs/2] because the spectral density is a symmetric function. With two signals, I would like to know if I can still do the calculation of the one-sided Cross Power Spectral Density with the formula Pxy(f) = 2 * Sxy(f) with f only over [0,fs/2].
